# Chartjs change horizontal axis value

Tags: javascript, chart.js

What options to set in Chartjs to change the horizontal axis value, from the code below to have a base value of 100, instead of 0.

[Chart to look like this, but y-axis base should be a 100 and not 0 as shown in the graph here.](http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/bar/vertical.html)

So, if a value of 70 is plotted on the bar chart, then it's y-axis should start at 100 to 70. While a value of 120, should start at 100 to 120 on it's y-axis.

[Mock up, Excel version of how it should look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRkU4.png)

I have tried some answers here but, unable to achieve this in Chartjs.

**Note:** I am working of the sample code from chartjs website. However, still can't get the specific scaling as needed.

**Chartjs 2.6.0**

```
var MONTHS = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
    var color = Chart.helpers.color;
    var barChartData = {
        labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Dataset 1',
            backgroundColor: color(window.chartColors.red).alpha(0.5).rgbString(),
            borderColor: window.chartColors.red,
            borderWidth: 1,
            data: [140,10,60,69,56,110]

        }, {
            label: 'Dataset 2',
            backgroundColor: color(window.chartColors.blue).alpha(0.5).rgbString(),
            borderColor: window.chartColors.blue,
            borderWidth: 1,
            data: [50,120,70,98,130,34]
        }]

    };

    window.onload = function() {
        var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
        window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: barChartData,
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                legend: {
                    position: 'top',
                },
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Chart.js Bar Chart'
                }
            }
        });

    };
```

**Edited** Removed Random numbers, and edited constants for testing purposes. I am currently looking into pluggins for Chartjs. This option might not be available in distributed package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Workaround Answer based of @adeel suggestions:**

So from the fiddle below, I used stacking on both y and x-axis, to get the desired effect. The first dataset (just an offset dataset) is used as the basis to stack the second dataset (actual) to get the desired effect.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1egzo49k/)

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var data = {
  labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June"],
  datasets: [{
    label: "Offset",
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    data: [50,100,70,60,100,100]
  },{
    label: 'Actual Dataset',
    backgroundColor: 'Blue',
    borderWidth: 1,
    data: [50,20,30,40,30,70]
  }]
};

var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: data,
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        stacked: true
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
      }]
    },
  }
});
```

Comment: It would be useful if it worked for dynamic datasets also.

Answer (score 5):

Just add

```
ticks: {           
    min:100
}
```

in your options under the y-axis scales your option should look like this.

```
options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes:[{
            ticks: {
                min:10
            }
        }],
    },
    responsive: true,
    legend: {
        position: 'top',
    },
    title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Chart.js Bar Chart'
    }
}
```

P.s: check the indentation because i was not using the editor.

**Edit** May be you have stacked in this case removed the stack type. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ozr79jzp/)

Comment: Thanks for the response @adeel, just trying it out. But, it looks like it's just cutting of at a 100, and not display values below 100. I wanted the bars to drop down from 100 if less 100, and stacked upwards above 100 if, more than a 100.

Comment: @GSari can you plz make a fiddle? it will be really helpful to the community and for me .Welcome :)

Comment: @GSari I have made a fiddle. In the edit you can see that fiddle.

Comment: made some modifications based of your suggestions below..thanks

Comment: @GSari I was not aware you were using stacked type or not so thats why i gave you a general answer. Because in your question you have not mentioned the stacked type.

Comment: Glad i could help :)

Comment: I agree I wasn't clear enough in the OP :), as I am learning chartjs, I initially thought there was an option in chartjs where we can move the x-axis anywhere up or down the y-axis so that any values plotted will behave like it does with a base of 0. Where bar values less than the starting value, will drop down, while higher values move upwards...Hope this can be made available in next release of chartjs. :)

Comment: yeah i hope. By the way good finding. +1 from my side for the finding. Cheers :)